# Install java Runtime Environment

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, java, mate

When running the `--help` switch, I got this.

```
$ /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/swriter
javaldx: Could not find a Java Runtime Environment!
Please ensure that a JVM and the package libreoffice-java-common
is installed.
```

I did a search for "jvm" and "java" but Package manager has many picks with "java" in the name.
What do I need?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install default-jre libreoffice-java-common
```

Description: Standard Java or Java compatible Runtime
  This dependency package points to the Java runtime, or Java compatible
  runtime recommended for this architecture